# Why does it not let me execute this?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ (1 week) , coding in general and I'm wondering how I can make this work, because I get errors whenever I compile & run. The idea is that the user inputs a gift code, and the program automatically opens it in a tab.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IKkm.png

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    string codes;
    cout << "Input here: \n";
    cin >> codes;
    for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
    {
        string site;
        site = "http://discord.gift/" << codes;
        
        ShellExecute(NULL, 
                     "open", 
                     site, 
                     NULL,
                     NULL, 
                     SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        Sleep(300);
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '3' to 'HINSTANCE__* ShellExecuteA(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, INT)'

[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'const char [21]' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
```

Comment: Please edit your code and any error you're receiving into your question as text.

Comment: There's no `operator <<` accepting `char const*` as first argument.

Comment: You should develop the habit of indenting your code correctly.  Regarding `ShellExecute`, you must be aware that there are two forms of that function.  One of these requires wide strings.  Without seeing all the errors, we can't guess whether this is also an issue (_e.g._ if your compilation settings specify unicode).  One thing for sure is that `std::string` does not automatically cast itself to a `const char*`, so you will need to call the `.c_str()` method to obtain a C string, after you've fixed the issue with constructing the string in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked. Next time I will indent and everything, I;m sorry, this was my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your code and errors in your question instead of just a pic would be a great idea.

Anyway, To add strings together you must use the + sign  `site = "http//..." + codes`

Not sure if there is any other errors but I highly recommend to [indent](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079) your code to make it easier to read

Comment: I think OP means std::string

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with your code:

- you are using `std::string` without `#include <string>`. While it is permissible for standard headers to include each other, you should not rely on this. Always `#include` relevant headers that your code needs.
- you can't use `operator<<` to concatenate a string literal with a `std::string` object. You need to use `operator+` instead:

```cpp
site = "http://discord.gift/" + codes;
```

- the `ShellExecute()` function does not accept a `std::string` as a parameter value, it takes `const char*` pointers instead. A string literal implicitly decays into such a pointer, but `std::string` does not.  However, `std::string` has a `c_str()` method to obtain such a pointer:

```cpp
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", site.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```